# Can client send data to server in TCP/IP communication

Tags: tcp, client-server, communication-protocol

To establish a connection normally we will send a data from server to client, but can data be sent from client to server.

Comment: Transfer-Control-Protocol; two-sided

Comment: @DOCASAREL *Transmission* Control Protocol.

Comment: @EJP You are right. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

To establish a TCP connection we will not just 'normally' but *always* send a connection request from the client to the server, acknowledge it from the server to the client, and acknowledge the acknowledgement from the client to the server.

This will normally be followed by a data request from the client and then a data response from the server.

Your question is based on a false premiss.